# Combining LINQ queries with method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to merge the following queries into a single call to the database.

```
string name = Item
              .Where(x => x.ItemID == 180)
              .Select(x => x.ItemName).FirstOrDefault();

int itemID = Item
             .Where(x => x.ItemName == name && x.Other == 50)
             .Select(x => x.ItemID).FirstOrDefault();
```

It's pretty much getting the name using it's ID, and using that name to get the ID of another row with the same name. The "Other" in this case narrows down the second query to a single result in this simplified example.

Comment: Are you expected the itemID in your second query to match the ItemID in the first query?

Comment: you already know the itemId chris. what do you want to do?

Comment: @bman7716 No otherwise I wouldn't need any of it?

Comment: @arslanaybars that might not be the case here. FirstOrDefault might actually return a different ID value than what was provided in the first query depending on whether the ItemName and Other are unique in the database. Chris, the "FirstOrDefault" limits your results to a single value, but does not guarantee that there is only one instance that exists in the database. SingleOrDefault does, but if more than one result is found an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I think it's not simple doing this since after filtering you want to filter the complete unfiltered list again, and doing it in one liner would produce an ugly and unreadable code:
        `var id = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemName == Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemID == 180)?.ItemName && x.Other == 50)?.ItemID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
int itemID = Item.Where(x => x.ItemName == Item.Where(y => y.ItemID == 180)
                 .Select(y => y.ItemName).FirstOrDefault() && x.Other == 50)
                 .Select(x=>x.ItemID)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This worked a treat, didn't know you could do it like a sub query. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working example if you choose to use a Join.

Example Data:

```
        List<Item> Items = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item { ItemId = 1, ItemName = "Item1", Other = 1 },
            new Item { ItemId = 2, ItemName = "Item2", Other = 2 },
            new Item { ItemId = 3, ItemName = "Item3", Other = 3 },
            new Item { ItemId = 4, ItemName = "Item4", Other = 4 },
            new Item { ItemId = 5, ItemName = "Item5", Other = 5 },
            new Item { ItemId = 6, ItemName = "Item6", Other = 6 },
            new Item { ItemId = 7, ItemName = "MyExpectedName", Other = 50 },
            new Item { ItemId = 8, ItemName = "MyExpectedName", Other = 50 },
            new Item { ItemId = 180, ItemName = "MyExpectedName", Other = 8 },
        };
```

Example query with a Join:

```
        var itemId = Items
            .Join(Items.Where(a => a.ItemId == 180), x => x.ItemName, y => y.ItemName, (x, y) => x)
            .Where(x => x.Other == 50)
            .Select(x => x.ItemId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that you will get a different ItemID than from the provided ItemID of 180 in this example. In this case, since I statically created this list as an example, I know that I will get ItemID of 7 returned every time. However, if this query is being run against an underlying database it is possible that the database won't return the items ordered by the ItemID (unless you tell it explicitly to do so using the OrderedBy clause). So it is possible that ItemId = 8 could be returned from the database as the first record set rather than 7.

Answer (score 0):

It can be simplified:

```
    var name = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == 180)?.ItemName;
    var id = Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemName == name && x.Other == 50)?.ItemID;
```

Comment: What if the item with `x.Other == 50` doesn't have `x.ItemID == 180` but the same `Name`

Comment: @KennethK. Please edit this sample with your approach: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hpQfpa

Comment: @MohamedElshawaf correct result but OP asked for a _single call to the database_ now you have 2

Comment: @fubo Ah, I got ya. Is it still Monday?

Answer (score 0):

This finds the `ItemName` of the item with `ItemID` 180 and uses it to filter all items by this value.

```
int itemID = (from i in Item
              where i.ItemName = (
                 from j in Item
                 where j.ItemID == 180
                 select j.ItemName).FirstOrDefault()
              && j.Other == 50
              select i.ItemID).FirstOrDefault();
```

This is in query syntax which I find much easier to read, but it's not to complex to convert to method call syntax if you prefer. ReSharper can do it automagically if you have it.

Comment: it would be helpful to explain what this query is doing. Also, Chris asked the question in fluent syntax so it might be useful to provide a comparative fluent example as well.

Comment: @bman7716 I added explanation. Method calls are more difficult to read and write, so I explained that too.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
Item
  .Join(Item, x => x.Name, x => x.Name, (x1, x2) => new {x1, x2})
  .FirstOrDefault(arg => arg.x1.ItemID == 180 && arg.x2.Other == 50)?.x2.ItemID;
```

But do you realy need single query?